# How to integrate ExtJS with Spring Framework

Tags: spring, extjs, inversion-of-control

How to integrate ExtJS with Spring IOC? I was able to integrate with Spring MVC?

Comment: You can't ExtJS is client side and Spring IOC service side. IOC and MVC are already integrated :)

Answer (score 0):

I've done this type of integration, but I encountered some problems. The best solution for my case was:

1. The entire system was created using Rest requests where the ExtJS
   through URL access query performed in the main application.
2. The structure was created using ExtJS MVC model. Helping build the models and structure requests.

A project like this is the Sonatype Nexus.
http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/